# How to add aditional parameter to all method users if parent method signature has been changed?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

Lets imagine I have method

```
public String test(int a){ return "";}
```

and methods users

```
var test = test(1);
var test1 = test(1);
```

Now Im changing parent method 'test' signature by adding one more parameter

```
public String test(int a, String b){ return "";}
```

Question: is there a way in intelij idea, to add some default value to all method users for newly added parameter in parent method? Because I have a lot of them and don't want to do it manually

```
var test = test(1,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the method and add the parameter in the editor, while the text cursor remains in the method's signature, an icon will appear in the gutter of the editor:

[image: Update usages to reflect signature change icon]

Now by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or clicking on the icon you can invoke `Update usages to reflect signature change`. This will allow you to specify a default value and will update all call sites.